# How to use touch events with an HTML5 <canvas> on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch-event

My goal is when you touch the left half of the screen it moves an object moves left, right when touching the right half, and does not move at all when the screen is untouched.

**Attempt**

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.touches[0].screenX;

    if(x < window.innerWidth/2){
        chase.dx = -chase.speed;
    }
    else if(x > window.innerWidth/2){
        chase.dx = chase.speed;
    }
    else {
        chase.dx = 0;
    }
});


window.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = e.touches[0].screenX;

    if (x > window.innerWidth/2 && chase.dx < 0)
        chase.dx = -chase.speed;
    if (x > window.innerWidth/2 && chase.dx > 0)
        chase.dx = 0;
    if (x < window.innerWidth/2 && chase.dx < 0)
        chase.dx = 0;
    if (x < window.innerWidth/2 && chase.dx > 0)
        chase.dx = chase.speed
});
```

Comment: what does your attempt do? it modifies `chase.dx` - so what?

Comment: chase.dx is change in x position of my one of my objects. It is drawn to the screen in another functionthis.updateGround = function () {
        if(this.x < -55 ){
            this.x += this.speed;
            this.draw()
        }
        else if(this.x > window.innerWidth - 150){
            this.x -= this.speed;
            this.draw()

        }
        else{
            this.y += this.dy;
            this.x += this.dx;
            this.draw()
        }
    }

Comment: Missing details here: 1) you're already capturing the event info correctly 2) looks like you want to fix the impl, not touch 3) do you want to drag your finger then also update in real time?